# Stacks convertion from postfix to infix

Tags: java, stack, postfix-notation

Hello I am practicing some stacks on Java and I am trying to do a problem concerning stacks. I was trying to write a method that takes a postfix notation and converts it into infix. This is what i have so far:

```
`
public void convertion() {
        Stack<Integer> stack;          // For evaluating the expression.
        stack = new Stack<Integer>();  // Make a new, empty stack.

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(postfix);

        int t1, t2 = 0;     //Operands

        boolean check = false;


        while (scan.hasNext() && !check) {
            if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                int operand = scan.nextInt();
                stack.push(operand);
            } else {
                char operator = scan.next().charAt(0);
                try {

                        while(stack.)


                } catch (EmptyStackException e) {
                    answer = "Malformed postfix expression";
                    check = true;
                }

            }
        }
        scan.close();
        try {
            answer = "" + stack.pop();
        } catch (EmptyStackException e) {
            answer = "Malformed postfix expression";
        }
    }
`
```

The part im having trouble with is on what i should put on the try part. Basically Im pushing all the numbers i find into the stack, but once i find an operator, how do i merge the two operands and the operator.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a very good case for first working out the algorithm using paper and pencil. Try some postfix expressions. Keep track of the state of your stack, and look at how it relates to the output you want. I don't understand why you are only putting Integer on your stack.

Answer (score -1):

You want to pop the top two stack elements, perform the appropriate operation on them and then push back the result:

```
try {
    int o1 = stack.pop().intValue();
    int o2 = stack.pop().intValue();
    switch (operator) {
        case '+': stack.push(new Integer(o1 + o2));
                  break;
        case '-': stack.push(new Integer(o1 - o2));
                  break;
        ...
    }
}
catch (EmptyStackException e) {
    ...
```

Comment: He isn't evaluating. He is converting postfix to infix.